# how to use url_title();

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I need help, we know CI basically load in url address "www.example.com/controller/function"
And my problem is: i want my url format look like "**www.example.com/controller/my-post-title.php**"

example:  **www.mysite.com/welcome/advance-php-codeigniter-course.php**

so, how can i do this.or anyone please suggest me how can i create in CI ***SEO friendly*** url

***i have one more question like:***

I used jQuery UI Datepicker and i save date with 'Y-m-d' format but i want ***echo*** date like 'd, M Y' format so, how can i also do this also.

Best Regards,
Rjony

Answer (score 0):

In your config/config.php file you can specify a "suffix" that will be added to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter. For example, if a URL is this:

```
  example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes
```

You can optionally add a suffix, like .php, making the page appear to be of a certain type:

```
  example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes.php
```

Please see for reference [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

**For Date**, you have to set date format in date picker js like this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'y, m d' }); // it shows in front
```

When you post your data that time get date and Also change date format using date-format.

Like this

```
date('Y-m-d', $get_date);
```

Then after save in database.

Comment: Hi, kruti.Thanks for you answer,But i did'n mean extension.My problem is full url structure not only .php or .jsp .suppose my url looks like: www.mysite.com/cntroller(name)/my-tile-post

Comment: you want to this type of url  www.mysite.com/cntroller(name)/my-tile-post in this url "sitename/controllername/functionname.php"